# WinSCP refresh codebase in PHP? How to refresh the server after seding a file using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

```
function upload(blobOrFile) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', './upload.php', true);
  xhr.onload = function(e) {};
  // Listen to the upload progress.
  var progressBar = document.querySelector('progress');
  xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
      progressBar.value = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
      progressBar.textContent = progressBar.value; // Fallback for unsupported browsers.
    }
  };

  xhr.send(blobOrFile);
}
```

I am using the above XMLHttpRequest to send a file to the server - the file size is 200KB - 400KB - the file is essentially on the server instantly - however, to see the file instantly, I have used the WinSCP ftp software refresh feature.

Is there a script or another way to do this automatically? I need another php script to access these uploaded files asap and process them? Right now the files are not visible to my php scirpt unless I manually refresh (using the WinSCP refresh feature).

Update:
I have 2 computers at 2 different locations. Both computers sending files using the upload.php script. Only after both uploads are completed, I can run the second php script. This is what preventing me from including the second php script in the upload.php. How can I resolve this without using WinSCP refresh feature? Below is the upload.php code:

```
$fp = fopen( 'savedfile.wav', 'wb' );
fwrite( $fp, $GLOBALS[ 'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA' ] );
fclose( $fp );
```

If WinSCP has a feature to refresh the server, then there can a codebase that can be included in the above upload.php or right after the "xhr.open('POST', './upload.php', true);"? What is it? Update 2: I added the following line to the above script hoping it might refreh - it did not refresh?

```
exec("touch -a './path/' . $filename");
```

Comment: What has to do a desktop application with some php script? I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  xhr.open('POST', './upload.php', true);
```

When you're making a request to `./upload.php`, you can process the uploaded file in that PHP script.

if you're planning to refresh those uploaded files in your WinSCP ftp software, then PHP script would not help you refresh it automatically. You need to manually refresh. Because the ftp tools doesn't have socket feature to update the files list automatically. you need to refresh them manually.

Comment: Thanks - I updated the post addressing your suggestion. I have 2 computers sending files and I need both files present before the second php is run. Can I still automatically refresh the server?

Comment: How both the uploads are connected to each other? As they are from two different systems. If this is only for two systems, then i would maintain a counter variable. When its value is 2 I'll run the second PHP script. Then will reset the counter variable again.

Comment: Both uploads are input to the 2nd php script, hence connected - it is for only two systems - the two files are always required. So your recommendation is to include the second php inside the upload.php with a counter? How will this counter know the second computer has sent the file - even if, the second file needs to be accessible by the first upload.php - it does not look feasible to me, correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Store the sender and the uploaded file info in a global object. So when first computer sends file, it will be noted in the object. Similarly when the second computer sends file it will be noted as well. No matter whether it's first computer which sends file first/second. Chck the object whether both the senders have sent the file/not and if the object contains both entries then process the second script.

Comment: I am a newbie - are there any sample scripts you could point me to? Appreciate it.

Comment: Even if a counter is introduced, a refresh might still be needed so the files can be accessed?